# Is it possible to use IronPython to execute a Python script with relative imports?

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

Is it possible to execute a Python 2 script using IronPython that allows relative imports? If not, is there a technical reason why?

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Attempted relative import in non-package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\test\test.py", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

This is expected, as normally one needs to execute using `python -m test.test`. Is there a way to replicate `-m` or execute as a module using IronPython?

### Code info

C# code to execute the Python script:

```cs
var scriptEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
var scope = scriptEngine.CreateScope();
var scriptSource = scriptEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"G:\test\test.py");
scriptSource.execute(scope);
```

test.py:

```py
from . import utils
utils.helloWorld()
```

Folder structure:

```
G:\
 |- test
     |- __init__.py
     |- utils.py
     |- test.py
```

Comment: guess you are running python 2, try changing `from . import utils` into just `import utils` in test.py

Comment: @Skycc Yes, that will work, and it's our current approach atm including adding paths, but I can't go deeper into another directory easily or make it clear that the import is from the current directory. Ideally, I want the replicate the module system.